# How to properly create initializers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I have a class `NewFormView: UIView` inside of which I have

```
var viewModel: NewFormViewModel
```

where `NewFormViewModel` has initializer:

```
var user: Users
init(for user: Users) {
    self.user = user
}
```

So I want: When I initialize my NewFormView to pass it the `user: Users` and initialize my `viewModel` with it. Like:

```
let newFormView = NewProfileFormView(user: user)
```

but when I'm trying to create initializers for `NewProfileView`:

```
init(user: Users) {
    super.init(user: user)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

I get error `Argument labels '(user:)' do not match any available overloads`. I've tried also with `convenience init` but got another error.
I think my problem is in thinking wrong. Could you please explain me how can I solve it and can call:

```
let newFormView = NewProfileFormView(user: user)
```

Comment: Hint: Initializers of a subclass of `UIView` must call one of the provided initializers of `UIView`. `UIView` does not have an `init(user: Users)` initializer.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I know. Thats why I tried it with `convenience init` where in the main init I tried to initialize with `frame: frame` and in convenience like `convenience init(frame: CGRect, user: Users)` but I got several errors again =/

Comment: May I suggest a thorough (re-)reading of the [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) chapter in the Swift book. It covers all of the little details you need to deal with when creating and initializing subclasses.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm still confusing. Maybe you could help me?

Comment: Update your question with more specific details about how you are still confused. And what's wrong with some of the answers you've received below?

Comment: @Christian's answer is good for me except I'm using `.xib` file for my view and I have to call this line `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`. But when I write it, it obviously asks me to define my `viewModel(user: Users)` property what I cannot do inside of `init(decoder)` as I do not have it there. I have `user` parameter only in the main `init`

Comment: That information needs to be in your question. Those are very important and relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.Xib` file for your view, you can init `UIView` like this:

```
var user: Users?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override init(frame: CGRect, user: Users) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
    self.user = user
}

private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("yourXibName", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
}
```

that *contentView* is a `@IBOutlet` of the main view in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create another init where you pass both user and the frame, for example

```
    class Form: UIView {
    private var model: FormModel!
    private var user: User!

     init(user: User, frame: CGRect) {
        self.user = user
        self.model = FormModel.init(user: user)
        super.init(frame: frame) //<-- since your view is derived from UIView, you need to set your base init 
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily  need to add the `frame` parameter. The `init(user:)` can pass some hardcoded frame if appropriate.

Comment: I tried that also. In this case I get `Property 'self.viewModel' not initialized at super.init call`

Comment: in your declaration try `var viewModel: NewFormViewModel!` @J.Doe

Comment: (sorry I didn't mean to add the second code, I've updated it) the reason you are having the first issue is because you'd need to initialize it within your coder init too @J.Doe

Answer (score 0):

```
 struct Users {
     var placeholder: String?
 }

 class NewFormView: UIView {
     var viewModel: NewFormViewModel

     init(user: Users, frame: CGRect) {
         self.viewModel = NewFormViewModel(for: user)
         super.init(frame: frame)
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }
 }

 class NewFormViewModel {
     var user: Users

     init (for user: Users) {
         self.user = user
     }
 }
```

Example Usage:

```
let formView = NewFormView.init(user: Users.init(placeholder: ""), frame: CGRect())
```

Where user follows your proper initializers for your Users struct/class and you give the frame the proper dimensions you expect the view to be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you're calling

```
super.init(user: user)
```

Your `NewFormViewModel` initializer has the signature init(for:) therefore you should change your code like this:

```
super.init(for: user)
```